# Core Data / Magical Record : Cannot find model for source store

Tags: ios, magicalrecord

Hi everyone,

I think I've read all posts about this problem over the Internet, here is what happens to me :

I'm using Magical Record and whenever I want to perform an auto migration, this error message occurs :

> Can't find model for source store

To perform this migration, I first create a new data model version, I set it as the current model version ( green checkmark etc... ), I modify it and I run the app.

In my appDelegate, I got this :

```
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:@"DataModel"];
```

"DataModel" corresponds to my `DataModel.xcdatamodeld` file.

The thing I noticed : when I display this DataModel in my finder and I select "Show Package Contents", I only have one file, named "content" which corresponds to my old version of my data model ( I don't see the new attributes I set on my new version ).
I should have two files : one corresponding to my old version and an other corresponding to my new version, right ?

Does anybody have an idea about how to solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you have another xcdatamodeld file? Maybe you are using a library that has a xcdatamodeld file.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I'll check all my libraries